# How can i make sure that pjl-comp-filter works properly with icefaces 1.8?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, gzip, icefaces-1.8

i have an icefaces 1.8 web application on IBMand i am using pjl-comp-filter to compress the response, after adding the compressor to the application it seems that it does not make any difference , how can i make sure that the compressor works properly?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the filter to `web.xml`?

You should add the filter and a filter-mapping. It should look something like this:

```
   <filter>
          <filter-name>CompressingFilter</filter-name>
          <filter-class>com.planetj.servlet.filter.compression.CompressingFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
          <filter-name>CompressingFilter</filter-name>
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
```